# Pass argument to file and paste the same in command

Tags: bash, shell

This is my .sh File

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/cassandra/bin/./cqlsh -e "COPY mykeyspace.sampletable(id ,name ,employee,address) TO '/opt/AllCsv/$csvName.csv' WITH HEADER = true AND delimiter = '|' ;"
```

I am trying to execute it by

```
./copy.sh companyname
```

This is not placing the argument value at "**$csvName**" position.
What went wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to a script is `"$1"`. If you want to use a variable `$csvName` then you have to assign it:

```
#!/bin/bash

csvName="$1"
/opt/cassandra/bin/./cqlsh -e "COPY mykeyspace.sampletable(id ,name ,employee,address) TO '/opt/AllCsv/$csvName.csv' WITH HEADER = true AND delimiter = '|' ;"
```